# How to properly proxy subdomains to another server?

Tags: nginx

I'm having trouble redirecting *.domain1.com on one server to *.domain2.com on another server as part of a migration process. Can someone clue me into how to set up the `proxy_pass` to do this? The following doesn't seem to work:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain1\.com$;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://$subdomain.domain2.com;
        }
    }
```

In the logs I get: `*1 no resolver defined to resolve subdomain.domain2.com, client: 72.***.***.*9, server: ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain1\.com$, request: "GET /index HTTP/1.1", host: "subdomain.domain1.com"`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a resolver directive in your location part.
If you have your own DNS server you can make it point to it, otherwise maybe 8.8.8.8 (Google one).
For more info, the official [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver).

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain1\.com$;

    location / {
        resolver ip.of.your.resolver;
        proxy_pass http://$subdomain.domain2.com;
    }
}
```